# Youtube video in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to insert a YouTube video in my application in angular 4

here the html:

```
    <div fxFlex id="visor-video">
        <iframe width="300" height="200"
          [src]="displayURL">
        </iframe>        
      </div>
```

Here the component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-unit',
  templateUrl: 'video-unit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['video-unit.component.css']
})

export class VideoUnitComponent implements OnChanges {


  displayURL;
  @Input() video: Video;


  constructor(public videoService: VideoService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.displayURL = this.getSantizeUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY');

  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.displayURL = this.getSantizeUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY');

  }
  sanitizedDisplayUrl() {
    return this.getSantizeUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY');
  }

  public getSantizeUrl(url: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
  }

}
```

But the sistem say that **"SafeValue must use [property]=binding: https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)"**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` instead of `bypassSecurityTrustUrl`

Use this code -

```
this.displayURL = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY');
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jytjaw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Several things related to general Angular use:
- Providers loaded in constructor won't execute until ngOnInit() hook. Don't try to use them in the constructor.
- The use of ngOnChanges() and sanitizedDisplayUrl() is redundant and useless here.

Regarding to your question, I would make a check in the template such as:

```
<div
    fxFlex
    id="visor-video"
    *ngIf=displayURL"
>
    <iframe
        width="300"
        height="200"
        [src]="displayURL"
    ></iframe>        
</div>
```

This way you prevent the program go into the iframe with displayURL = null. This might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: `*ngIf` is juse avoid error , it will not help in any way for this use case